# Raspberry Pi + LED Video Processor and resolution issues

Tags: led, framebuffer

I'm working on trying to get a P6 LED screen (connected via a NovaStar TB2 video processor). I've been playing with various options in `config.txt` but I can't seem to get it to display properly. This is how it comes up in default mode:

[image: Current setup]

The video processor should support 1080p according to [the manual](https://www.ledcontrollercard.com/media/wysiwyg/Novastar/TB2/Novastar%20TB2%20LED%20Display%20Video%20Control%20BoxSpecifications-V1.0.0.pdf), but it's coming up subpar.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Never seen one before but my first question would be - does it work with a 'normal' PC plugged into the HDMI or does it need the software mentioned in the booklet to get running?  I would be tempted to plug in a PC / Mac and see what it auto configures to via HDMI and via their software.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the Pi. Just a regular Pi 3. It works just fine. This is a configuration issue really. My guess is that it has something to do with the pixel density or that I need to pass on some very custom variables to `hdmi_timings` in `config.txt` or similar.

Comment: Sorry - I meant does the processor work with a PC?  The guide seems more software driven than HDMI :-)

Comment: Ah, right. Yeah, that's not possible unfortunately. The LED isn't driven by HDMI. The processing unit takes HDMI in, but the out is over an Ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work by manually tweaking the `hdmi_timings` in the end.

Comment: Upvote for the people that ask and keep trying in parallel. Good work OP.